# dynamic filter based on record.account value

Tags: admin-on-rest

```
const filterVal = (record) => ({
     name: record.account,
});

<ReferenceArrayInput {...props} source="access_id" reference="awsroles" label="AWS Roles" sort={{ field: 'id', order: 'DESC' }} filter={filterVal} 
     allowEmpty>
<SelectArrayInput source="id" />
```

I'd like to add a dynamic filter in the ReferenceArrayInput based on one of the value in record. However, it is not working for some reasons. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
var filterVal = (props) => {
    return {AwsAccountId: props.match.params.id};
};

<ReferenceArrayInput source="access_roles" reference="awsroles" label="AWS Roles" sort={{ field: 'id', order: 'DESC' }} filter={filterVal(props)} allowEmpty>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out AOR Dependent Input.

https://github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input

You can wrap the SelectArray Input in an HOC. This way you can intercept the record being passed to SelectArray input and change it to your needs.

Something like this.

```
const higherOrderComp = WrappedComponent => props => {
  return <div ><WrappedComponent {...modifyRecord(props)} /></div>
}

const modifyRecord = (props) => {
   //do something with props.record .....
}
```

NOTE - make sure that modifyRecord makes a clone of props and then modifies it. Never try and modify input properties directly.